# Query nested object in mongodb without key

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have multiple documents saved which look like the one shown below, how would I query against a nested object without the ID to receive the right document?

Here is what I current, but this doesnt work, as I dont have the ID at the start.

```
db.collection.find({
  "details.hardware.id": 5,
})
```

This is what ive tested and know works but I dont know the ID -

```
db.collection.find({
  "100201.details.hardware.id": 5,
})
```

Document example -

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "6338b69062433c04642d26ca"
    },
    "100201": {
      "broken": true,
      "details": {
        "build": {
          "id": 1018458,
        },
        "hardware": {
          "id": 5,
          "model": {
            "id": 131,
          },
        },
        "id": 2811302,
        "view": {
          "id": 781,
        }
      },
      "id": "100201",
      "links": [
        {
          "details": {
            "id": 7832,
          },
          "id": 15012,
        },
        {
          "description": null,
          "details": {
            "id": 6528,
            "model": {
              "id": 530
            }
          },
          "id": 15076,
        }
      ],
      "ref": false,
    }
  }
]
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you narrowing the result set first with other query predicates or is this dynamic one the only filter? What you're asking for can be done, but it won't be able to use an index. So if it is the only filtering criteria then your app will scan the full collection every time the query is executed which won't be scalable or successful long term

Comment: Im not currently narrowing it down, and I dont think I have much to narrow it down either. So I'd have to scan the full collection which has around 400 of these documents, I guess it might just be better to change my code and set the hardware id as the actual id of the document so its easier to query

Comment: Using any data as field names is widely considered an anti-pattern with MongoDB.  As you've discovered, using data `"100201"` as a field name creates problems when you want to query later.